# Changing result display based on Element value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that contains info for college classes. The classes are displayed by title, course number and total number of credits.

My XSLT groups the data by area of study and then lists the classes by course number and provides the course description and total number of credits. Everything is working fine, but I'd like to tweak the final display of credit hours.

Each class has a minimum # of credits 1-4. Some classes have a maximum # of credits.

My XSLT pulls both the minimum credits `<CRSMINCRED1>` and the maximum credits `<CRSMAXCRED1>` if they exist.

Then, the XSLT builds the final display so it appears as one of the following:

When the class data features only `<CRSMINCRED1>` the display looks like this:
"1 credit hours"
"2 credit hours"
"3 credit hours"
"4 credit hours"

When the class data features both  `<CRSMINCRED1>` and `<CRSMAXCRED1>` the display looks like this:
"1 to 4 credit hours."

Everything's fine except for the first item. When the course has only "1" minimum credit and no maximum credits, I'd like the the display to be:

"1 credit hour"

I've tried to make a "variable" and "if" statements without success.

Here's some sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CrystalReport>
<Details Level="1">
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<CRSTITLE1>Clinical Applications of CT I</CRSTITLE1>
<DEPTSDESC1>Diagnostic Medical Imaging</DEPTSDESC1>
<CRSNO1>2511</CRSNO1>
<CRSMINCRED1>3</CRSMINCRED1>
<CRSMAXCRED1/>
</Section>
</Details>
<Details Level="1">
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<CRSTITLE1>Clinical Applications of CT II</CRSTITLE1>
<CRSDEPTS1>DMI</CRSDEPTS1>
<DEPTSDESC1>Diagnostic Medical Imaging 2</DEPTSDESC1>
<CRSNO1>2512</CRSNO1>
<CRSMINCRED1>1</CRSMINCRED1>
<CRSMAXCRED1>4</CRSMAXCRED1>
</Section>
</Details>
<Details Level="1">
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<CRSTITLE1>Clinical Applications of CT III</CRSTITLE1>
<CRSDEPTS1>DMI</CRSDEPTS1>
<DEPTSDESC1>Diagnostic Medical Imaging 3</DEPTSDESC1>
<CRSNO1>2513</CRSNO1>
<CRSMINCRED1>1</CRSMINCRED1>
<CRSMAXCRED1/>
</Section>
</Details>
</CrystalReport>
```

Here's a portion of the XSLT that I'm trying to get to work:

```
<xsl:template match="CrystalReport">
...
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/CRSMINCRED1|Section/CRSMAXCRED1"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section/CRSMINCRED1">
<xsl:if test=". = 1">
<mincredit><xsl:value-of select="."/></mincredit><xsl:text> credit hour</xsl:text></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test=". &gt; 1">
<mincredit><xsl:value-of select="."/></mincredit><xsl:text> credit hours</xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section/CRSMAXCRED1[string-length() != 0]">
<xsl:text> to </xsl:text><maxcredits><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></maxcredits><xsl:text> credit hours</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet produces what I want until the class shows both minimum and and maximum credits and then I get the following display: "1 credit hour to 4 credit hours"

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="CrystalReport">
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Section" mode="credits"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="credits">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMINCRED1" />
    <xsl:text> credit hour</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMINCRED1[. != 1]" mode="pluralize" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section[normalize-space(CRSMAXCRED1)]" mode="credits">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMINCRED1" />
    <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMAXCRED1" />
    <xsl:text> credit hour</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMAXCRED1[. != 1]" mode="pluralize"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CRSMINCRED1">
    <mincredit>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </mincredit>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CRSMAXCRED1">
    <maxcredit>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </maxcredit>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="pluralize">
    <xsl:text>s</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```